# Get OS from Remote Computer (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I am looking to determine if a remote computer is Windows, Mac or Linux by computer name or I can resolve IP if that helps?

I have tried using TTL but it seems PowerShell 7 test-connection doesn't have TTL. I then downgraded PowerShell and played around with TTL and related but was hoping for a better method?

I am aware of the `$isWindows`, `$isLinux`, and `$isMacOS` but not sure how to call them on a remote computer.

Comment: `(Get-CIMInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName «whatever»).Caption`, perhaps?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin On unix systems there is no `WMI` or `CIM` so that wouldn't work. Instead you can use `[System.Environment]::OSVersion` and grab the platform (i. e. Win32NT and UNIX) with `[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform` and get the version with `[System.Environment]::OSVersion.VersionString`

Comment: How cam I use [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform on a remote computer?
I will look it up shortly so may answer my own question.
Does it matter which PowerShell?

Comment: NMAP with the os option and command line might be ab answer for remote computers. 

I can't find a means to call [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Platform from a remote computer